# Why does my jPanel doesn't show an embed webView from Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, jfxpanel

I don't know much about JavaFX, but I need to show a WebView onto a JPanel in a JFrame.
Here's my code

```
public class Ventana extends javax.swing.JFrame {


        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        
    public Ventana() {
        initComponents();
        
        panel.add(jfxPanel);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            WebView webView = new WebView();
            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
            webView.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
        });
    }
}
```

This is my main method from where I'm opening my jFrame

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Ventana jf_ventana = new Ventana();
        jf_ventana.setVisible(true);
        
    }
```

The code I used says this

```
// Creation of scene and future interactions with JFXPanel
// should take place on the JavaFX Application Thread 
Platform.runLater(() -> {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        webView.getEngine().load("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
    });
```

It doesn't crash or anything, but is not showing anything either

Comment: I am not JavaFX dev so I may be wong, but don't you need some `main` method in which you would actually *use* that class? How do you actually start/run this code?

Comment: I don't know, I'm showing the jFrame on another class. Like this: `public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Ventana jf_ventana = new Ventana();
        jf_ventana.setVisible(true);
        
    }`

But I don't know if I need more for the JavaFX

Comment: Please include that in your question, so we would have [mcve].

Comment: This is still not a minimal reproducible example.  If it were somebody could just copy and paste the code to compile and run it without addiition or change, and they can't do that with what you have provided.